# Opening XML file located in addin folder

Tags: .net, excel, vsto

In a VSTO Excel addin the code:

```
Dim XMLDoc As XElement = XElement.Load("XMLFile1.xml")
```

generates a `FileNotFound` error with the message ("*Could not find file 'C:\Users\doug\Documents\XMLFile1.xml'.*")  It's looking in the My Documents folder but the XML file is located in the VS Projects folder for that project.
I have set the XML file's "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy always".  When I change the code to include the full path to the XML file the code works.

Also, if I include the above code in a Windows Console or other type of project it runs correctly.  I'm only getting it in the Excel Addin.
The above is true for VSTO 2008/Excel 2003 and VSTO 2010/Excel 2010.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use the relative path, the current directory (`Environment.CurrentDirectory`) is used to resolve that path. In the case of a VSTO Add-in this is set to the user documents folder automatically. However for a console application that value is set to the same folder as the executable and that is why you are experiencing different behaviors.

If your file will be deployed to the same folder as your VSTO Add-in assembly you can use (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`) to build the full path to the file.

Example, in C#:

```
string filename = "XMLFile1.xml";

string path = Path.Combine(
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    filename);

XElement.Load(path);
```

Comment: @João, this is brilliant. Not sure how you found this gem, as I've been Binging all day and couldn't find an answer to this VSTO problem. Your answer was spot on! Thanks so much!

Comment: All VSTO solutions I made used ``Environment.CurrentDirectory`` to get working directory, that always worked till yesterday, I first took it as a VS bug since it is relative environment variable. I tried to change VS working dir in many way ... no success. Thanks very much @João

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
```